# Segmentation fault error during the copying to buffer

Tags: c, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I write code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        char * var=(char*) calloc(10, sizeof(char));
        strncpy(var,"123456789",9);
        strncpy(var, "abcdefghi",1000000 );
        printf("This is var == %s\n",var);

}
```

but after compiling and running him I have `Segmentation fault` error. If I change maximum copy character in the line `strncpy(var, "abcdefghi",1000000)` to 10 then it's work fine. But I really don't understand why `segmentation fault` error is occurring in my case.

Comment: @HAL9000, IMO it's not really intuitive that `strncpy` filles the whole buffer always.

Comment: Once you have read the manual (and the comments) the only conclusion is that you rarely need strncpy(). Just don't use it. Until you really need it (which may take a few years). Management summary: strncpy() := red_flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strncpy` always pads up to the end of the buffer, so this line:

```
 strncpy(var, "abcdefghi",1000000 );
```

causes the segfault.

As you can read [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strncpy/) The remainder of the buffer is filled with `\0`.

Comment: But `strncpy(var, "abcdefghi",1000);` doesn't cause segfault. I'm confused.

Comment: @Dmitrii: it is _undefined_ behaviour. _anything_ can happen. (possibly the heap or malloc()s internal bookkeeping structures have been damaged, and the error will occur later. Or not)

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, now I'm understand it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Because you allocate 10 bytes:

```
char * var=(char*) calloc(/*HERE->*/10, sizeof(char));
```

and try to copy 1000000 bytes to it.